# Eclipse - Find and Replace Dialog Always Opening Maximized

Tags: eclipse, replace, dialog, find

The Find and Replace dialog in my copy of Eclipse always opens maximized.  Is there a way within Eclipse to control the behavior of the dialog so it opens as a smaller popup window?  The same issue is occurring when I set Run Configuration environment variables.

I am using Eclipse Neon (yes, I know--many versions behind the current).  I have not had this problem until recently.  I cannot think of any changes I made myself that would have caused this behavior.

Comment: Which operating system (if Linux, which UI and GTK version)? Which additional installed plug-ins? Can this be reproduced with the current Eclipse version?

Comment: The OS is MacOS High Sierra.  There are too many installed plug-ins to list them all here.  No new ones had been installed before the problem started. The current Eclipse version works fine.  I am just hoping that someone knows of an Eclipse preference that can be set.

Comment: _"No new ones had been installed before the problem started."_ I guess you mean only _not immediately before_. Did you upgrade Eclipse immediately before? There is no such preference. Have you installed a Genuitec (Darkest Dark Theme, Webclipse, etc.) plug-in and if so, will the issue disappear when you uninstall it? Can you reproduce the issue with a new workspace? Why don't you want to use the latest version of Eclipse?

Comment: No, I did not upgrade Eclipse immediately before. I have not installed the plugins you listed, and I double-checked to see if the happened to be installed.  The issue can be reproduced with a new workspace.

Comment: Then I don't understand why you think it is caused by Eclipse itself and not by an installed plugin or something else. Anyway, it works with the current version. That is why tools should always be kept up to date. Problem solved.

Comment: The only plugins I have installed are the ones that were packaged with the Eclipse version I downloaded.  They are all up-to-date. They all show Eclipse as the provider.  No 3rd party plug-ins are installed.

Comment: Because you wrote _"The current Eclipse version works fine."_ I assumed your question is answered. The size of the dialog of the very first time it is opened can be configured in an ini file, not via UI. Then Eclipse saves the last position in an XML file within the `.metadata` of the workspace folder. Therefore, the suggestion of @techi-santosh to change the size to trigger a new save with new values. But maybe the size is set e. g. by a (multiple) monitor manager tool. I also didn't found any error report of this issue.

Comment: Thank you!  Your info about .metadata helped me find the cause: an outdated .lock.  I have edited my original post to show the solution.

Comment: Please give a self-answer instead of editing your question. Nice that it works now. Nevertheless, I recommend you to upgrade. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be a .lock file in the .metadata folder. It had a date from many months prior and apparently was prevented the resizing of the dialogs to be saved.  I deleted the .lock file and restarted Eclipse.  Now the resizing of the dialogs is saved and reused whenever the dialog is opened.

Nevertheless, I did upgrade to the latest Eclipse.  I just wanted to solve the problem first in case the solution might be applicable to future version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Just resize the File/Replace window and again try to open again.
It should work.
Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not solve the problem.  The next time I open it, it is maximized again.

Answer (score 0):

i was also in the discomfortable situation of having a big file/replace window that was hiding the code. right clicking on the title bar permitted me to resize it, and size was kept at next eclipse restart.

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions worked for me. I'm using LiClipse, and I've got the newest version--8.1.0--and in fact this problem didn't start until recently, when I upgraded to 8.1.0.

The .lock file was from three years ago, but removing it didn't help. Also, NONE of my dialogs are resizable.